# How to use sql tables on local machines when i have MAMP installed?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I installed MAMP on my mac to run sql and apache server on my local machine to host a website i am working on. Now i am using phpmyadmin to control and create my database tables. I am running into a couple of issues with inserting values into the tables. I have two pages namely, test.html and test.php. test.html has a form with username and password and it calls a javascript to post the values to test.php.Following is code snippet of how i am posting the value on test.html.

```
$.post("test1.php",
 {
 username: username,
     password: password

  },
 function( dataFromServer ){
     alert(dataFromServer);     
 }
);
```

I am unable to insert the two values in the table. When i click submit, i receive the following error in firefox:

POST http://localhost:8888//test1.php
500 Internal Server Error

Following is code snippet of how i insert values on test.php:

```
include('config.php');
$tbl_name="table1";
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(col1,col2)VALUES('$username','$password')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Can anybody point the mistake here. I am new to web coding so this might be really trivial.

Thanks,
-B

Comment: does test1.php have executable permission ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question. I did include config.php file at the top of test.php which connects to local database as follows: $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root").

Comment: use ls -l to see permission of test1.php and if it don't have executable permission. give it executable permission using chmod command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 internal error means there is something wrong in your php file.
Check the following things

1.Is there any syntax error in your php file.

2.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(col1,col2)VALUES('$username','$password')";
```

should be written as

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(col1,col2)VALUES('".$username."','".$password."')";
```

Also,always sanitize data before you use it.

Comment: `username=bobby%27%29%3Bdrop+table+table1%3B--&password=epic`

Comment: Yeah and please sanitize your data.It means that you remove the unwanted malicious parts from your input